# How can I rotate \pi by 180 degrees?

Tags: amsmath

Is it possible to generate a flipped version of symbol `$\pi$` using packages `\usepackage{amsmath, amscd, amsthm, amssymb, mathrsfs,amsfonts,graphicx}`

Comment: Using just those packages? Not easily. Using `graphicx`, it's just `\rotatebox{180}{$\pi$}`.

Comment: Or `\reflectbox{$\pi$}`, depending on what "flipped" means to you. This also needs `graphicx`.

Comment: @ jlv \reflectbox{.} has worked. Can u make it an answer?

Comment: @NAASI Flipping and rotating are quite different actions. The title doesn't agree with the body of the question.

Comment: Is it possible that you are looking for \amalg?

Comment: Better name of this tread: How can I rotate `\pi` by `\pi`.

Comment: @ wipet....that might be a catchy title but the \rotate{.} commands takes in numerics so I think its better this way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is general possible to flip any sign with the `graphicx` package (see [graphicx documentation](ftp://ftp.mpi-sb.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) sections 4.2 and 4.3). Because it is not fully clear to me what "flipped version" means (if simply rotated or also mirrored) I give hear a guess, which can easily be modified if you needed something slightly different.

In my solution I show also a simple rotated `\pi`, which suffers from the used origin for the rotation. This can be corrected by an additional argument to the `\rotatebox`, which sets the origin to the center of the sign. For the flipped version I use a `\scalebox` to mirror the rotated sign. Using only a `\scalebox` seems to me not possible, because it cannot adjust the origin.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*{\flip}[1]{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\rotatebox[origin = c]{180}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    Unflipped: $\pi$\\

    Rotated: \rotatebox{180}{$\pi$}\\ % rotate

    Rotated better: \rotatebox[origin = c]{180}{$\pi$}\\ % rotate around center

    Flipped: \flip{$\pi$}\\ % flip = rotate + mirror

    Flipped without rotation: \scalebox{-1}[1]{$\pi$} % alternative flip
\end{document}
```

The result looks like

[image: output of code above using pdflatex for compilation]

**EDIT:**

As barbara suggests, the upright mirrored version was missing. I added it as "alternative flip" or "flipped without rotation" respectively.

Comment: i'd interpret "flipped" (in the absence of a more precise description) as possibly the pi still being upright.  may as well add that for excruciating completeness.  (nice answer)